# What does this command in robots.txt do?

Tags: search-engine, robots.txt

I am wondering what the following code in Robots.txt does.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*?
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `Disallow: /*?` tells the robot(s) not to fetch any URL that contains a `?` on this host.

This seems to be an extension to the official standard that [only Googlebot supports](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449&from=40367&rd=1).

Comment: Wow nice, didn't know about that!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `*` is not a wilcard character in the [original robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html). So parsers that don't support various robots.txt extensions will interpret the `*` as the character itself.

For those parsers the rule would be interpreted as: "All bots, don't crawl URLs that **start with** `*?`.

For example these URLs would be blocked:

- `example.com/*?`
- `example.com/*?.html`
- `example.com/*?foobar`

While these URLs would *not* be blocked:

- `example.com/foo*?`
- `example.com/foo*?.html`
- `example.com/foo*?foobar`

Answer (score 0):

It means "disallow crawling of pages that include question marks in their address bars for all search engines". Because question marks are used to separate query parameters from the script name, it will basically block your dynamic content from being indexed. For example `index.php` will be crawled, but `index.php?page=main` will be disallowed from crawling.

Generally, Robots.txt is used to block/allow search engines to crawl parts of your website. It can contain three directives: User-agent, Allow and Disallow. User-agent means search engine:

```
User-agent: *
```

means all search engines, whereas you could also be specific about what particular search engine you would like to disallow. For example, to block Google from indexing your web-site your could write in robots.txt:

```
User-agent: Goolge-bot
```

You can find the list of search engines for robots.txt [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/db.html).

Allow and Disallow respectively list folders or files that are allowed/disallowed for crawling. It uses regex syntax.

```
Disallow: /
```

means "do-not crawl anything on my website". You can combine disallow and allow like this:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /*?
Disallow: *.jpg
```

basically means "allow crawling of dynamic links (pages containing question marks), but do not allow crawling of JPG image links". [Here is more detailed description](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449) of robots.txt from Google.